# Spark structured streaming file processing is very slow, when clean source is enabled to archive

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, spark-structured-streaming

I'm having a spark structured streaming job where source is S3 and sink is S3.

When I'm disabling cleanSource, for a 5 Million records, throughput is 3500 rec/second.

For the same pipeline, if I enable cleanSource to archive and provide archiveDirectory, throughput is reduced to 200 rec/second.

When I was going through spark source code, I found that spark archival part is handled by a daemon thread, ideally in this case spark main processing thread is not given any overload.

Is there any reason, why this overhead occured?

Thank you.

Comment: if the code is doing rename() then that'll kill things.

Comment: Hey @stevel,

Code is not doing any rename(), it is moving the files to archive directory as it is. I increased spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.cleaner.numThreads to 10, now it's littlebit faster, i.e,, 500 rec/seconds, but still performance is very bad.